# Is Drupal right choice for this kind site?

Tags: php, api, drupal, cakephp

I run a small Domain & webhosting reseller business. recently, my upstream Provider has start giving a HTTP/JSON based API. so I was thinking to make a site using that REST API. the end result that I am expecting is similar to http://www.beta.namecheap.com/ but lot simpler with less options

The site would have have

- Domains: check availability,transfers & new registration via http api
- Webhosting: Shared(Windows & Linux)
- Customer Contact creation: Registration form with submits data to HTTP API via POST method
- Shopping chart system,Live Chat for support
- Facebook & OpenID integration.

So tell me people, is a CMS framework like drupal right choice for this kind of site? should I look at some other CMS? OR I am better off in doing custom build cms using phpframework like cakephp or Symphony?

I need some advise on this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Drupal, yes. There are modules that integrate OpenID and Facebook Connect already. Ubercart provides a full shopping cart out of the box. Users can register, or you can write a custom hook to save users that fill out a contact form to save contact info. Look at Webform module. You can also write the service to check for domains in a small simple module.

You can definitely do this a lot faster than writing it yourself.

Comment: Can you please explain "writing the service" part? Any Existing modules similar to this or some documentation/howto on how to proceed?

Comment: There is a Services module that will more than likely help you out. By default, Drupal comes with xmlrpc. You can also write a small module, include nuSOAP library, and perform web calls. But the Services module might save you some time. http://drupal.org/project/services

Comment: If I am not wrong Services module is geared more towards creating servers. Whereas what I want to do is create a http client in drupal for making calls to external REST server. Upon some searching found that there is drupal_http_request() function, which I can use for the same.http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request

Comment: Thats what I meant in my above comment instead of xmlrpc- juggling too much here. But yeah, Drupal can facilitate what you need without much effort.

Comment: Thanks for telling me its possible, I start reading Drupal Docs.

Comment: No problem. You will quickly find there isn't much you can't do in Drupal.